# Debug SQL Server table's trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have triggers on a table that is preventing the table rows to update. How to debug SQL Server triggers in Management Studio when updating rows in a table?

Comment: Look at the DDL of the trigger, and work out what it is that is blocking the statement you're performing. A well written trigger will easily show what it is doing, should be `THROW`img helpful errors, and be minimal so you'll have very little code to debug. If it's none of these things, the trigger itself likely needs a rewrite or shouldn't be a trigger.

Comment: Can you share the trigger's code?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is not possible in sql 2018. Using 2017 to debug is an option.